# How Much is Adobe Paying For The Tag Icon Image?

Tags: discussion, advertising, sponsored-tags

Seriously, WTF guys?

[image]

Comment: how much did they pay?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed "Exact Duplicate" -- the other thread didn't seem to address the question of how much Adobe paid...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How much do I have to pay to get a **vampire** icon on the [vampire](/questions/tagged/vampire) tag on meta? Can I trade in some of my large, arbitrary number to make that happen? What's the point of large, arbitrary numbers if I can't cash them in for cheap prizes at the front desk?

Comment: I vote for a picture of the count from Sesame Street, assuming there's enough resolution to make it out.

Answer (score 24):

I don't understand the "Seriously, WTF guys?"  Adobe pays them, they get their logo on tags that are associated with their products.  The site is supported, tags get a nice visual indicator, the site owners are paid for their efforts...I'm not seeing the issue here.

Comment: my user experience get cluttered with unmatching colors and shapes I don't want to see!

Comment: they are better than more flashy flash ads.

Comment: **@tharkun:** Add `.post-tag img { display: none; }` to your user style sheet if it bothers you that much.

Comment: If this is what it takes for SO to stick around, I'm all for it. Servers, bandwidth, and development aren't free.

Answer (score 12):

I like it, and hope they eventually expand it to use more icons, advertised or not.  Why? Because it makes it *extremely* obvious to new users that they've chosen a known good tag.  Don't see the little icon next to your main tag?  You've probably done something wrong.

---

Hmm... I'm gonna promote this to a feature request:
[Show an icon for all "common" tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24001/show-an-icon-for-all-common-tags)

Comment: No icon for the `subjective` tag, then!

Comment: That's subjective.

Comment: Arg... why do people keep voting for this?  The question is closed.  Go vote for my feature request instead!

Comment: @Joel: Don't worry. I didn't vote for this answer *at all*.

Comment: I don't like it and don't want to see it expanded because more icons make my eyes bleed and make using SO unpleasant.